# Ant deployment: Error: Unknown user permission: AIViewInsightObjects

Tags: deployment, ant

I'm trying to deploy the admin profile from ant successfully.

My package.xml is such as :

```
<types>
    <members>Admin</members>
    <name>Profile</name>
```

`

I am deploying it to the sandbox from production but getting error :

```
 profiles/Admin.profile -- Error: Unknown user permission: AIViewInsightObjects
```

Comment: Probably sandbox has some settings enabled that enables AIViewInsightObjects to Salesforce. You may have to remove it from package xml for deployment, that is a workaround. Roght solution would be to sync that feature in sandbox as well as production.

Comment: BTW, probably worth considering moving from Ant to sfdx since Ant is no longer being actively developed and maintained.

Comment: Thank Raul and Phil for replying and  as per workaround I removed those permissions from the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this Salesforce [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003vhEQAQ&title=metadata-deploy-to-a-sandbox-org-fails-on-user-permissions-which-are-not-enabled-in-sandbox-orgs), these kinds of errors are standard deployment errors during deployment. In general, these errors are returned when you try to deploy permissions that don’t exist in the destination organization.

Workaround : Remove references to the user permissions from the profile in source Org or as Raul mentioned sync that feature in destination Org.